# Subtracting roots of unity. Specifically $\omega^3 - \omega^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

This is question that came up in one of the past papers I have been doing for my exams. Its says that if $\omega=\cos(\pi/5)+i\sin(\pi/5)$. What is $\omega^3-\omega^2$. I can find $\omega^3$ and $\omega^2$ by De Moivre's Theorem. But I cant make much headway into how to subtract these? 
The answer they give is $2cos(\dfrac{3\pi}{5})$

Please, some help will be greatly appreciated. I cant seem to find help over the internet either.

Comment: Since they're roots of unity, you could appeal to a geometric interpretation (since there will be no scaling, only rotation).

Comment: The marking scheme requires an algebraic argument.I understand that    since there are constant angles between each root. But how do I prove it algebraically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\cos(3\pi/5)$ and $\cos(2\pi/5)$ are closely related, as are $\sin(3\pi/5)$ and $\sin(2\pi/5)$.

**Remark** If you are familiar with the complex exponential, note that $\omega^2\omega^3=e^{i\pi}=-1$. So we are looking at $e^{3\pi i/5}+e^{-3\pi i/5}$, which is $2\cos (3\pi/5)$.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my post. That's what the marking scheme says. But how are they related? Could you please explain in some more detail.

Comment: By the addition laws, and in other ways, $\cos(\pi -2\pi/5)=\cos\pi\cos(2\pi/5)-\sin\pi\sin(2\pi/5)=-\cos(2\pi/5)$. Similarly, but more familiarly, $\sin(2\pi/5)=\sin(3\pi/5)$.

Comment: Ah! I see. So how did you know that one must subtract pi form 2pi/5. Whats the underlying intuition. I understand in this case but how would I do it more generally?

Comment: I was trying to give a "trig" solution. The real intuition comes from complex numbers. I have added a remark about that.

Comment: Indeed I am familiar with the exponential form. But I don't understand the second part of your remark. Say if I wanted w-W^4 what would i do then? I suspect (W^4)x(W)=W^5. Then?

Comment: In the same way, $\omega\cdot \omega^4=-1$, so $\omega^4=-\omega^{-1}=-e^{-\pi i/5}$. So $\omega-\omega^4=e^{\pi i/5}+e^{-\pi i/5}=2\cos(\pi/5)$.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much I finally get it.

Comment: If it not too much trouble could you point me resource that deals with further details about roots of unity and its properties?. Wikipeida goes over my head!

Comment: You are welcome. Very soon this will seem easy. I am sorry, cannot think of a standard source. Much of the discussion gets number-theoretic, and not easy.

Answer (score 0):

$$\omega=\cos(\pi/5)+i\sin(\pi/5)$$
$$\omega^3-\omega^2=\cos(3\pi/5)+i\sin(3\pi/5)-(\cos(2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi/5))$$
$$\omega^3-\omega^2=\cos(3\pi/5)-\cos(2\pi/5)+i(\sin(3\pi/5)-\sin(2\pi/5))$$
$$\omega^3-\omega^2=\cos(3\pi/5)-\cos(2\pi/5)+i(\sin(3\pi/5)-\sin(2\pi/5))$$
$$\omega^3-\omega^2=-2\sin(\pi/2)\cdot\sin(\pi/10)-2i\cos(\pi/2)\cdot\sin(\pi/10)$$
$$\omega^3-\omega^2=-2\sin(\pi/10)$$
$$\omega^3-\omega^2=-2\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$$
$$\omega^3-\omega^2=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

use some trig. formula:
$\cos C-\cos D=2\cdot \sin\dfrac{C+D}{2}\cdot \sin \dfrac{D-C}{2}$

and $\sin C-\sin D=2\cdot \cos\dfrac{C+D}{2}\cdot \sin \dfrac{C-D}{2}$

and $\sin (\pi/10)=\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}{4}$

Comment: Thanks. I have question what if I wasn't familiar with that trig formula.  how would I do that then? I a three mark question. There must be a shorter way?

Answer (score 0):

$$\overline{\omega}=\omega^9 \Rightarrow \overline{\omega^3}=\omega^{27}=\omega^7=-\omega^2 \,.$$

Thus

$$\omega^3-\omega^2= \omega^3+\overline{\omega^3}=2 Re(\omega^3) \,.$$

Comment: I am sorry but what does w with the bar mean? I haven't come across that.

Comment: @Googeygoo Conjugation.

Comment: The complex conjugate of omega equals W^4? Could you mention the general rule, what if I had omega to some other power?

Comment: @Googeygoo Note that $\omega \times \bar\omega =1 = \omega^5$. Cancel $\omega$. You can do the same for any power of $\omega$, check the last part of my proof.

Comment: Okay so if you multiply a number and its conjugate you get one. So W^3 and its conjugate equal one. I cant seem to get how does that equal W^3xW^2.

Comment: @Googeygoo No. $z \bar z =|z|^2$, where $|z|$ denotes the absolute value (modulus). Because roots of unity have absolute value 1, for $\omega$ you get 1.... And $\omega^3 \omega ^2=\omega ^5$... Since $\omega$ is a fifth root of unity, $\omega^5=...$?

Comment: W^5=-1? correct?

Comment: @Googeygoo Ups, fixed the proof now :)